# SP Lists - JSON Conditional formatting based on other columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am trying to set up conditional formatting for my SharePoint list, based on the value from different columns.

Here is what I was trying to set up:

1. IF @ColumnName1 = "status 4" THEN @ColumnName2 be highlighted red if the cell is blank.
2. IF @ColumnName3 = "" THEN @ColumnName4 be highlighted red if the cell is blank.

And more functions similar to them.

I have written some code, but I am not entirely sure how to create argument reference to another column. How this can be done?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/233951/get-other-field-value-in-json-column-formatting

Comment: You can get the current column value using `@currentField` and other fields can be referenced as for example: `[$DueDate]`.

Comment: @Ganesh Sanap 
So here's my condition (what I want to set up): [link]IF Status = "status 4" THEN Current Field be highlighted red if the cell is blank

And here's my code:
'code'{
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(AND([$Status] == 'statust 4',@CurrentField == '') ,'sp-field-severity--blocked,'')"
  },
   {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }   
}
Do you know what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Use SharePoint JSON column formatting for your columns like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if([$Status] == 'Status 4' && @currentField == ''), 'sp-field-severity--blocked, '')"
  },
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

Where `Status` is the internal name of your SharePoint list column. You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)