# Customizing SharePoint Online, question and training

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting

I am new to sharepoint online and I am used to having the flexibility of doing api calls to create custom parts and add css.  It seems like the only option with spo customization is Formatting Rows or Columns, is this true?  Can anyone refer any training resources for higher level customization or dev?

When using column formatting is it possible pull a field from another column?
Or is that only for row level formatting?
Also when formatting a row level is it possible maintain the filtering at the top even if you put all the content/data within single divs for each row?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you may be looking for is custom client-side solutions using the SharePoint Framework (SPFx).

With the SharePoint Framework, you can create custom web-parts with whatever controls/functionality you need, or you can create "extensions", which include field customizers which allow you more control over field customization than just the JSON formatting.

Here is the MS documentation on the [overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview).

Here is the [overview of SPFx web parts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/overview-client-side-web-parts).

Here is the [overview of SPFx Extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions).

Comment: thank you I'll check this out. :)

Answer (score 0):

For the rest of the questions:

[Column formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) is more about how the list data is **displayed** than how they can be managed.

So features like “*pull a field from another column*” would have restriction and possibly not achievable. ([Reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/233951/get-other-field-value-in-json-column-formatting).)

Also, some of the formatting disable the ability of filtering (or sorting), based on what syntax or elements you use.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: @RachealSass You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a really basic layout.  I found out that when you recreate your own styling of the rows it wipes out the filtering at the top.  You need the columns you reference to be in the view.  Intellisense with vs code is a savior.  And these three videos are great starter help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lco-0K_jCRM